# How to prove $e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac{x}{n}\right)^n$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Define
$$e=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n,$$
how to prove that 
$$e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac{x}{n}\right)^n,$$
for all $x$.
Thank you.

Comment: What is your definition of $a^b$ for $a>0$ and $b\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: $a^b$ is $a$ raised to the power of $b$.

Comment: I'm not asking how you _read_ $a^b$, I'm asking for a _mathematical definition_ of $a^b$.

Comment: see definition here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation

Comment: That link is not a definition, it's a collection of encyclopedic facts about exponentiation. Besides, they mention non-integer powers as involving the exponential function… If you don't give us what your definition of $a^b$ is, we can't answer in non-circular ways.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: This question is not about the definition of exponentiation!You might as well ask, "What is your definition of $\mathbb R$?"

Comment: @TonyK: OP's result involves an (non-integer) exponentiation… so don't blame me if I ask what definition of exponentiation is used before I even consider answering the question.

Comment: Here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BlCf0-bOnCE

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: But the extension of exponentiation to real exponents is completely unproblematic.

Comment: If you can't edit your answer to give a proper definition of $a^b$; if you can only link to random pages or videos for that, it means that you actually don't know what $a^b$ means, so your question is not really a mathematical question.

Comment: your answer is also not really a mathematical answer too.

Comment: @kong: Don't worry about gniourf_gniourf. Obviously they're in a bad mood about something today :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Showing that $ \displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{r}{n} \right)^{n} = e^{r} $.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/828320/showing-that-displaystyle-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-left-1-fracrn)

Comment: I think that [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function) might be exactly that you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the definition

$$
e = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n
$$

Then

$$
e^x = \left( \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n \right)^x
= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{nx}
= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{x}{nx} \right)^{nx}
= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{x}{n} \right)^{n}
$$

Comment: Can you justify each equality by mentioning  the theorems which you used?

Comment: That last step where you draw the power of x into the brackets to attain $(1+x/n)$, how is that true?

Comment: Write $\frac{1}{n}$ as $\frac{x}{xn}$ and then use that $nx$ goes to infinity as well - so replace $nx$ by $n$...

Comment: @Chellapillai: I have no idea how those theorems are called - we learn them we use them and we forget the names...

Comment: Okay. Just I would like to know that whether we have to use the fact that $y\mapsto y^x(y\in[0,\infty))$ is continuous or something else?

Comment: Replacing $nx$ by $n$ is not allowed here as $n$ is an integer and $nx$ may not be an integer.

Comment: It is nowhere written that $n$ is an integer. It is a limit that goes to infinity, and both $n$ and $nx$ go to infinity (for $x \ne 0$...

Comment: @johannesvalks: By convention, $n\to\infty$ implies that $n$ is a positive integer unless explicitly stated otherwise.

Comment: @Paramanand: Infinity is not a number, it is a concept. Therefore infinity is never an integer.

Comment: @johannesvalks: I am not saying that $\infty$ is an integer. I am saying that $n$ is an integer.

Comment: @Paramanand: $\lim_{x \rightarrow\infty} x = \lim_{x \rightarrow\infty} \lfloor x \rfloor \Big( 1 + \frac{x-\lfloor x \rfloor}{\lfloor x \rfloor} \Big) = \lim_{x \rightarrow\infty} \lfloor x \rfloor = \lim_{\lfloor x \rfloor \rightarrow \infty} x$

Comment: @Paramanand: it is irrelevant for the limit that goes to infinity to distinguish integers from non integers in this case.

Comment: @johannesvalks: you seem to suggest that when $n\to\infty$ then it does not matter that $n$ is an integer or not. But it does matter! $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin n\pi = 0$ if $n$ is positive integer. If $n$ is not a positive integer then this limit does not exist.

Comment: @Paramanand: You have missed my words "in this case". So examples of other cases are irrelevant.

Comment: @johannesvalks: I know that in the current question it does not matter if $n$ is integer or real, but this fact is not obvious and very difficult to prove. Hence I want to highlight the issue.

Comment: @Paramanand: Now we are talking! This is a good reply. In this case it is clear, and you ask to 'prove' it...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15545/discussion-between-paramanand-singh-and-johannesvalks).

Comment: @johannesvalks: you should see my post http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2014/05/theories-of-exponential-and-logarithmic-functions-part-2_10.html in order to understand why it is not clear/obvious and why it needs a proof.

Comment: @Paramanand: Now for me the chat is new... I went there but how do you reply?

Comment: @Paramanand: What you wrote on you blog is *based* on $n$ as integers.

Comment: @johannesvalks: yes in that post $n$ is an integer and towards the end of http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2014/05/theories-of-exponential-and-logarithmic-functions-part-3.html i show the case when $n$ is real. Here I use variable $t$ instead of $n$. (see equation $(14)$ of this post).

Answer (score 1):

Let $\frac{n}{x}=t$. Then as $n$ goes to infinity, $t$ does too. Therefore by considering the given definition of $e$ we have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac{x}{n}\right)^n=\lim_{t\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{t}\right)^{xt}=(\lim_{t\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{t}\right)^{t})^x=e^x$$

Comment: please explain why you vote down to the answers...

Comment: I don't understand the downvote either. It's true that you have used a real number $t$ in place of the (presumed) integer $n$, but that doesn't deserve a downvote.

Comment: why i am not allowed to use the continuity of $a\mapsto a^x$? Is there any answer that the continuity is not used in it?

Comment: @Fermat: You method is correct and there is no need to assume that $n$ is an integer. Voteup!

Comment: @johannesvalks: Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

By applying $\log$ and  using L'Hospital's rule $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)}{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\frac{1}{1+\frac{x}{n}}\left(\frac{-x}{n^2}\right)}{\frac{-1}{n^2}}=x$$