# Prob. 6 (d), Chap. 1, in Baby Rudin, 3rd ed: How to complete this proof?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, analysis

Here is Prob. 6, Chap. 1, in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition:

> Fix $b>1$.

Problem 6(a):

> Let $m$, $n$, $p$, $q$ be integers such that $n>0$, $q>0$, and $r = m/n = p/q$. Then [I've managed to] prove that
> $$ b^{m/n} = b^{p/q}.$$ So we can reasonably define $b^r$ as $$b^r \colon = \sqrt[n]{b^m}.$$

Problem 6(b)

> [From this definition we can] prove that $$ b^{r+s} = b^r \cdot b^s, $$ where $r$ and $s$ are any rational numbers.

Problem 6(c):

> Now for a rational number $r$, let the set $B(r)$ be defined as follows:
> $$B(r) \colon= \{ \, b^t \colon \, t\in \mathbb{Q}, \, t \leq r \, \}. $$
> Then it is clear that $$b^r = \sup B(r).$$ So for every real $x$, we can define $b^x$ as follows: $$b^x \colon= \sup B(x) = \sup \big\{ \, b^t \, \colon \, t \in \mathbb{Q}, \, t \leq x \, \big\}. $$

Problem 6(d):

> Using this definition, (we are required to) prove that, for every pair of real $x$ and $y$, the equation $$b^{x+y} = b^x \cdot b^y$$ holds.

My Attempt:

> If $r$, $s \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $r \leq x$ and $s \leq y$, then $r+s \in \mathbb{Q}$ also and $r+s \leq x+y$ so that we can write
> $$ B(x) \cdot B(y)  = \{ \, b^r \cdot b^s \, \colon \, r \in \mathbb{Q}, s\in \mathbb{Q}, \, r \leq x, s\leq y \, \} \subseteq \{ \, b^t \, \colon \, t \in \mathbb{Q}, \, t \leq x+y \, \} = B(x+y),$$ and hence
> $$b^x \cdot b^y = \sup B(x) \cdot \sup B(y) = \sup \{ \, b^r \, \colon \, r \in \mathbb{Q}, \, r \leq x \, \} \cdot \sup \{ \, b^s \, \colon \, s \in \mathbb{Q}, \, s \leq y \, \} = sup \{ \, b^{r+s} \, \colon \, r \in \mathbb{Q}, \, s\in \mathbb{Q}, \,  r \leq x, \, s \leq y \, \} \leq \sup \{ \, b^t \, \colon \, t \in \mathbb{Q}, \, t \leq x+y \, \} = \sup B(x+y) = b^{x+y}.$$
> Here we have used the following definition: Given two non-empty sets $U$ and $V$, say of real numbers, we define the set $U \cdot V$ as follows:
> $$U \cdot V \colon= \{ \, u \cdot v \, \colon \, u \in U, \, v \in V \, \}.$$

And we have also used the fact that if $W$ and $Z$ are two non-empty bounded above subsets of the set of positive real numbers such that $W \subseteq Z$, then we must have
$$ \sup W \leq \sup Z.$$

So far, we have shown that $$b^x \cdot b^y \leq b^{x+y}.$$
Now how to prove the reverse inequality using the machinery developed above?
That is, how to prove that $$b^{x+y} \leq b^x \cdot b^y?$$

Comment: Use a sequence $(t_n) \to x+y$ where $t_n\in\mathbb Q$ to reduce it to the same identity with $x,y\in\mathbb Q$.

Comment: AlexR, sequences and their convergence are to be discussed later on in Rudin's text; so we should avoid them for this problem in the interest of rigor, I suppose.

Comment: You can find one solution here: http://minds.wisconsin.edu/handle/1793/67009

Comment: This solution is not satisfactory @wellynaught. Because, if you read it, that solution "cheats". It consider $B(x)=\{b^t|t<x;t\in \Bbb{Q}\}$. While the book (Rudin) defines $B(x)=\{b^t|t\leq x;t\in \Bbb{Q}\}$. Is exactly this equality that is causing trouble. If it were only "$<$", we would be done.

Comment: Under Rudin's framework, I would explore his section on using Dedekind cuts, which should "snap in" nicely with this definition of irrational exponentiation.

Answer (score 4):

By definition $b^{x+y} = \sup B(x+y)$, where $B(x+y)$ is the set of all numbers $b^t$ with $t$ rational and $t<x+y$. Then any rational number $t < x+y$ can be written as $r+s$ where $r,s$ rational and $r<x,s<y$ (Think about why this is true). Hence we can write $B(x+y)$ as the set of all numbers $b^rb^s$ with $r<x,s<y$, this means that $B(x+y)$ is the set of all products $uv$ where $u\in B(x)$ and $v\in B(y)$.

Since any such product is less than $\sup B(x) \sup B(y)$, we can write $M= \sup B(x) \sup B(y)$ is an upper bound for $B(x+y)$. On the other bound, suppose $0<c<\sup B(x) \sup B(y)$, then $c/(\sup B(x)) < \sup B(y)$. Let $m=\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{c}{\sup B(x)}+\sup B(y)\right)$. Then $c/(\sup B(x)) < m < \sup B(y)$, and $\exists u \in B(x), v \in B(y)$ s.t. $c/m < u, m<v$ Hence we have $c=(c/m) \times m < uv \in B(x+y)$, and so $c$ is not an upper bound of $B(x+y)$. It follows that $\sup B(x) \sup B(y)$ is the least upper bound of $B(x+y)$. Then we have this equality $b^{x+y}=b^xb^y$ as required.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Since $m= \frac{1}{2} \frac{c}{\sup B(x)}+\sup B(y)$, clearly $m\gt \sup B(y)$. But you say $m\lt \sup B(y)$.

Answer (score 3):

Right now, there are five answers: [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1098812) that isn't actually an answer, [two](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1098912) [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1098951) use concepts like limits and continuity the Rudin book hasn't tackled by this point, and [two](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1102706) [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3752487) are correct but rely on redefining the set $B(x)$ from Rudin's definition $B(x) = \{b^t: t \in \mathbb{Q}, t \leq x\}$ to $\{b^t: t \in \mathbb{Q}, t < x\}$.

This redefinition is okay because $sup\ \{b^t: t \in \mathbb{Q}, t \leq x\} = sup\ \{b^t: t \in \mathbb{Q}, t < x\}$.  I thought it might be useful to show why this is true using the tools we have so far.

Let's define $B(x)$ as Rudin does, with $t\leq x$.  Let's define $C(x) = \{b^t: t \in \mathbb{Q}, t < x\}$.  I will show $sup\ B(x) = sup\ C(x)$.

Note that $C(x) \subset B(x)$. Thus, since $sup\ B(x) > y$ for all $y \in B(x)$, $sup\ B(x) > y$ for all $y \in C(x)$, and $sup\ B(x)$ is an upper bound of $C(x)$.

Pick $z < sup\ B(x)$.  We know $sup\ B(x) >0$ since $b^t>0$ for all $t\in \mathbb{Q}$.  Thus we can pick some positive real $w$ with $z<w<sup\ B(x)$.  Then $w$ is not an upper bound of $B(x)$ so there exists $p\in\mathbb{Q}$ with $p\leq x$ and $b^p>w$.

By the work in Problems 7a-c, we know there exists a positive integer $b$ such that $b^n < \frac{b^p}{w}$.  (Note that this is not a circular reference, since the work in 7a-c does not reference anything in Problem 6.)  Then $\frac{1}{b^n} > \frac{w}{b^p}$.  Then $b^p\frac{1}{b^n} > b^p\frac{w}{b^p}=w$.  Since $w>z$, we have $b^p\frac{1}{b^n} > z$.

Note $b^p\frac{1}{b^n} = b^{p-1/n}$, $p-\frac{1}{n}\in\mathbb{Q}$, and $p-\frac{1}{n}<p\leq x$.  Then $b^{p-1/n} \in C(x)$, and $z$  not an upper bound of $C(x)$.

Thus $sup\ B(x) = sup\ C(x)$, and it is equivalent to show that $sup\ C(x+y) = sup\ C(x)sup\ C(y)$ as two others have done above.

Comment: Surprised to see that this is the only complete answer online for a problem in the first chapter of the most famous math book, worse still, that this is not the one which was awarded the bounty.

Answer (score 2):

I am stuck in the same question. Maybe we can think together. :)

I've divided into two cases: $x+y\notin \Bbb{Q}$ and $x+y\in\Bbb{Q}$.

**Case 1:$x+y\notin \Bbb{Q}$**

Well, as you've done, we have that $B(x)\cdot B(y)\subset B(x+y)$. Ok.
So, let $b^t\in B(x+y)$. Then $t\in \Bbb{Q}$ and $t<x+y$, since $x+y\notin \Bbb{Q}$. So, we have $t-y<x$ and, therefore, $\exists r\in(t-y,x)\cap\Bbb{Q}$. Set $s=t-r\in\Bbb{Q}$. Thus, we have
$$t=r+s<x+y, \text{ with }r<x \text{ and } s<y.$$
And so, $b^t=b^{r+s}=b^rb^s$, by item (b) of this exercise 6. But $b^r\in B(x)$, and $b^s\in B(y)$. So $b^t=b^rb^s\in B(x)\cdot B(y)$.

We've proved then that $B(x+y)\subset B(x)\cdot B(y)$ and, hence, $B(x+y)=B(x) \cdot B(y)$.
Then $$\sup B(x+y)=\sup B(x) \cdot B(y)$$ $$=\sup B(x) \cdot \sup B(y),$$ since $B(x),B(y) \subset [0, \infty )$.

But, what about the case $x+y\in \Bbb{Q}$? I haven't done great advances on it.. :( Can you guess anything?

Comment: @Saaqib Mahmuud

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.

Comment: I've done it. I've added a bounty! ^_^ @Paul

Answer (score 2):

Since $b^{x+y}=\sup\{b^t:t\in \mathbb Q,\ t\le x+y\}$, we know that $\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists r\in\mathbb Q$, $r\le x+y$, such that $b^r>b^{x+y}-\epsilon$.

**Claim:** $\exists r'\in\mathbb Q$, $r'\lt x+y$, such that $b^{r'}>b^{x+y}-2\epsilon$.

If $x+y \notin \mathbb Q$, $r'=r$ satisfies the condition. Let's suppose $r=x+y\in\mathbb Q$, and consider $r'=r-\frac 1 n<r$. Since $b^r-b^{r'}=b^r(1-b^{-\frac 1 n})$, we only need to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}b^\frac 1 n = 1$, and then choosing $n$ large enough, $r'$ is what we need to find. This is an easy exercise in calculus.

Now we can prove part(d) of the problem. Write $r'$ as $p+q$, where $p\le x$ and $q\le y$ are both rational. This is possible because $r'<x+y$ and rational numbers are dense. Hence, $b^x\cdot b^y\ge b^p\cdot b^q = b^{r'}>b^{x+y}-2\epsilon$. Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, $b^x\cdot b^y \ge b^{x+y}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you have shown that $b^xb^y \leq b^{x+y}$ then it is enough to to show that $b^xb^y \lt b^{x+y}$ is false.
To show this, define:
$$b^x = sup\{b^t | t \in \Bbb Q \land t \lt x\}$$
which is different from Rudin's but is equivalent.

Suppose $b^xb^y \lt b^{x+y}$. Then there must exist $r \in \Bbb Q$ with $r \lt x+y$ such that $b^{t_1}b^{t_2} \lt b^r$ for all $t_1, t_2 \in \Bbb Q$ with $t_1 \lt x$ and $t_2 \lt y$.

Note: Since $b \gt 1$, if $u, v \in \Bbb Q$ and $u \lt v$ then $b^u < b^v$.

So if we find $s, p \in \Bbb Q$ with $s\lt x$ and $p\lt y$ such that $r\lt s+p$, we would prove that no such $r$ as described above exists, because $r\lt s+p \implies b^r \lt b^{s+p} = b^sb^p$.

So let $\varepsilon = x+y-r$. By the Archimedean property, there exists a natural number $n$ such that $n\varepsilon \gt 1$ so $\varepsilon \gt 1/n$.
From $r = x+y-\varepsilon$ it follows that $r + \frac 1n \lt x+y$ so $$r\lt x+y -\frac 1n$$
Now choose $s$ such that $x- \frac 1{2n} \lt s \lt x$ and $p$ such that $y- \frac 1{2n} \lt p \lt y$. So:
$$p+s \gt x - \frac 1{2n} + y - \frac 1{2n}=y+x- \frac 1n \gt r$$
Just like we wanted, so we can conclude that $b^xb^y \lt b^{x+y}$ is false. And therefore $b^xb^y = b^{x+y}$.