# Baby Rudin: Chapter 1, Problem 6(d). How to complete this proof?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, analysis, real-numbers

I've searched for a question, and it has been already asked here [Baby Rudin: Chapter 1, Problem 6{d}. How to complete this proof?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1004514/baby-rudin-chapter-1-problem-6d-how-to-complete-this-proof/1098812#1098812), but it hasn't yet a satisfactory answer. Can you help? If you go there, you'll see I've done the case $x+y\notin \Bbb{Q}$. Can you guees something about the case $x+y\in \Bbb{Q}$?
 Thanks!

Comment: C'mon guys. Open bounty +100 for that question...

Comment: in the original question a comment has been added pointing to the solution of the exercises in the book...

Comment: Yes. I've checked it, but it's not satisfactory. If you read it, that solution "cheats". It consider $B(x)=\{b^t|t<x;t\in \Bbb{Q}\}$. While the book (Rudin) defines $B(x)=\{b^t|t\leq x;t\in \Bbb{Q}\}$. Is exactly this equality that is causing troubles. @Thomas

Comment: See this [solution](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~b89089/book/Rudin/Rudin_1.pdf), pp. 2-3 .