# What are some ways of thinking about exponentiation, other than repeated multiplication?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question

For instance, we can think of exponentials as solutions to differential equations. Are there any other interesting ways of describing exponents without iteration of multiplication?

Answer (score 1):

Using the exponential function ([with different characterisations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function)) $e^x$ and the natural logarithm:

For every $a, b \in \mathbb R$, we can write $a = e^{ln(a)}$ (suppose for now $a>0$) which implies
$$a^b = (e^{ln(a)})^b = e^{b\cdot ln(a)}$$
See [these great answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55068/can-you-raise-a-number-to-an-irrational-exponent) for more detail.

In fact, this allows to expand the concept of exponentials to the complex plane:

Given $z, w \in \mathbb C$, we define 
$z^w = e^{w\cdot ln(z)}$ (where $ln(z)$ is the [complex logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm)), and use the fact that for $w = a + i\cdot b$:

$$e^w = e^{a+ib}=e^a\cdot e^{ib} = e^a(cos(b)+i\cdot sin(b))$$
since $exp(x+y)= exp(x)\cdot exp(y)$ and $e^{ib} = cos(b)+i\cdot sin(b)$.

However, note that this is a multi-valued function unless a branch of the complex logarithm is chosen (otherwise $(e^{ln(z)})^w \neq e^{w\cdot ln(z)}$).

Answer (score 1):

If a function's growth rate is proportional to its value then it's an exponential function.

i.e.  $b^x$ is growing at the rate $c_b*b^x$ for some constant $c_b$.  $b^x$ is the one function where that can be true.

Which allows for the "how can you multiply something by itself 1/2 a time to get $b^{1/2}$" question to be "how much do you have at 1/2 if the instantaneous grate of growth always proportional to the current ammount?"  Of course, that's a pretty hard question to answer without circular reasoning, but it does make non-integer and even non rational exponents meaningful.

Comment: I like this different answer. $\color{white}{+1}$

Answer (score 0):

From the category theory point of view, you can adress a lot of exponentials.

For example, in the category of Sets, an exponent of two sets is the set of functions from one to another

> ( A hint to see why it makes sense: how many functions exists from a set $A$ to a set $B$?
>   Answer:
>
> > $|B|^{|A|}$ where $|X|$ is the cardnality of a set $X$
>
> )

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_object

Answer (score 0):

If you go one step beyond multiplication...

$$a^b=\underbrace{a\times a\times a\times\cdots\times a}_b$$

$$a\times b=\underbrace{a+a+a+\dots+a}_b$$

And combine these to turn exponentiation into addition.

$$\color{white}{\text{Way too many additions, so I left it out.}}$$

Take these farther steps, and you'll create the [hyperoperation sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation).