# Can you raise a complex number to a transcendental exponent?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, exponentiation

For example, how do I find the value of:

$$ (\cos(e) + i\times\sin(e))^{\frac{\pi}{2}} $$

I've did a bit of searching and found this [amazing question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55068/can-you-raise-a-number-to-an-irrational-exponent), and it gave me two ways "to raise a non-complex number to an irrational power":

> 1. You can pick a sequence of rational numbers $x_n$ converging to $x$ (i.e., $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n = x$) and define $$a^x = \lim_{n\to\infty} a^{x_n}.$$
> 2. You can use the exponential function $e^x$ (defined in many ways, say as $e^x = \lim_{n\to\infty} (1+\frac{x}n)^n$ or with a power series), and its inverse the logarithmic function that satifies $e^{\ln t} = t$ for all positive $t$, and since $a = e^{\ln a}$, define $$a^x = e^{x \ln a}.$$

The first way won't work with transcendental numbers such a $ \pi $, $ \frac{\pi}{2}$ and its family.

The second way will end up giving me $ \ln(i) $ in an exponent, which I'd rather not endure right now.

I tried De Moivre's, but I noticed that it only works for integer powers.

So how should I approach $(\cos(e) + i*\sin(e))^{\frac{\pi}{2}} $?

Comment: what do you mean with $e$ in the argument of sin and cos?

Comment: Euler constant, probably. Though it is very uncommon to use that.

Comment: Sure.  But if you do, beware that you have a branch cut like any other noninteger exponent.

Comment: @OP: You can always use method 1. E.g., $4-\frac43+\frac45-\frac47+...$ converges to $\pi$.

Comment: Euler formula is an extension of de Moivre theorem that also works for real powers.

Comment: you can also have a look at WA, there are several formulas

Comment: Check out [De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula).

Comment: Also I suggest using `\times` for $\times$ because it is a more correct way to write multiplication (in this case); and there is a method to zoom math formulas (right click \ Math Settings \ Zoom Trigger \ Double-click then double-click at the formula), so including the "that tiny exponent" part is often unnecessary.

Comment: Yes I meant the Euler constant,. @user202729: Thanks, I'll try doing that.

Comment: To be honest, this equation was from a trickier problem that I've simplified by using Euler's formula and arrived into this part, I couldn't figure out how to use Euler's formula to simplify it further, thanks. ----- I've used \times for x and deleted the unnecessary line.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner what is WA?

Comment: @ArandomUserNameEG [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ (\cos e + i \sin e) ^ {\pi \over 2} $$
$$ = \left( e^ {i \times e} \right) ^ {\pi \over 2} $$
(by [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula))
$$ =  e ^ {i \times \left({\pi \over 2} \times e\right)} $$
$$ = \cos \left({\pi \over 2} \times e\right) + i \sin \left({\pi \over 2} \times e\right) $$

Warning: As *GEdgar* wrote in the comment below, because of branch cut, $e^{x\times y}=\left(e^x\right)^y$ is not true for all complex $x$ and $y$. [Wikipedia reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Failure_of_power_and_logarithm_identities).

Comment: Now, that's an elegant solution, I didn't know you could use Euler's formula like that!

Comment: You didn't know it?  Good.  Because the "law" $(e^a)^b = e^{ab}$ is in general false for complex $a,b$.