# How do I prove continuity in this case_

Tags: calculus, continuity

Fix $\alpha ,\beta\in\mathbb R$  and define a function $f$ from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ such that 
$$f(x)= 
 \begin{cases}
    x^{\alpha} + 3        & \quad \text{if } x\le 1 \\
    x^{\beta} + 3  & \quad \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}$$

How do I prove that f is continuous?

Any hint? I am stuck.

Thank you

Comment: Your function is not well defined for some values of $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Math_QED How is it not well defined?

Comment: For example, what is $(-1)^{1/2}$?

Comment: Even if the point doesn't exist, all that matters is that $1)$ -  $f(1)$ exists, $2)$ - the limit of $x$ to $1$ of $f(x)$ exists, and that $3)$ - $1)$ is equal to $2)$. [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55068/can-you-raise-a-number-to-an-irrational-exponent) proves that we can express $a^b$ as $e^{b \ln a}$, so $1^b$ is well-defined for real numbers.

Comment: Well, then what is $\ln(-1)$ in the real numbers? Clearly this function is badly defined for certain values as the output does not give real numbers.

Comment: @Math_QED $x$ can't be changed to $-1$.

Comment: But the function is defined on the real numbers, in  particular on the negative real numbers?

Comment: You are right, we should bound alpha and beta to obtain a well defined function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a matter of noticing that$$\lim_{x\to1^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to1^+}f(x)=4=f(1).$$